# Bind classes to Global Scope in ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, ecmascript-6

i'm trying to recreate jQuery validator in **ES6** *without using any jQuery,* and i've kinda hit a roadblock in trying to recreate it's functionality for adding validation methods by using the *Global scope*, that is if you call `Validator.addMethod` anywhere, it'll run the associated function in the `Validator` and add a method to the `Validator`.

I can't seem to do this in ES6 since i'm not allowed to export my class to the Global scope, my class is **never accessible from the window object**, like for instance *jQuery* is, without this anyone who wants to add a new validation function would have to `import` a new function to add it class, and i cannot simply call

```
Validator.addMethod('required', function(element, value){
  return value.length > 0;
})
```

On any file i want after loading the validator class, so my question is, is this really impossible in ES6 or am i missing something? I already know it's not the best of practices and would be open to suggestions but the idea is ease of use even for people not well versed in ES6.

Comment: So this validator runs on the front-end? where are you writing it? is it isomorphic?

Comment: @duxfox-- It only runs on the front-end, i have a separate PHP validator running on the server

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ES6 and above has been designed to avoid polluting the global scope. Your concerns are just *the solution to a lot of evil bad coding practices in JavaScript*.

BTW, you can always access `window` object and add a property called the same way as your class:

```
class Validator {}

window.Validator = Validator;
```

...because a class is still a constructor function and prototypal inheritance wrapped by a class-based syntax.

If you're going to distribute your library both in browsers and NodeJS, you might want to do this:

```
class Validator {}

var global = window || global;
global.Validator = Validator;
```

BTW, if you want to do things in the right way, you can distribute your library using the universal module definition. [Learn more at the official GitHub repository of Universal Module Definition (UMD)](https://github.com/umdjs/umd).

Comment: Or use `globalThis`