# How to dynamically instntiate a class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have a class and a function, as follows:

```
class A {} 
function B {}
```

I need to dynamically instantiate them, in a way similar to Java's `class.forName()`.

I am able to instantiate the function as follows:

```
new window["B"]
```

However

```
window["A"] === undefined
```

Why the difference? Aren't classes just syntactic sugar for functions?

Comment: "*Aren't classes just syntactic sugar for functions?*" mostly they are. But what you get here is the new scoping rules from ES6. Any `let`, `const`, and `class` declarations are *not* automatically added to the global object. Hence why you cannot get `A` from there. It'd be similar to having `const C = function() {}`. Although, not *exactly* the same - class constructors cannot be called without `new`. At any rate, if you need [“variable” variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530) just use an object or a map and put your classes there. You can then fetch them by string.

Comment: Also related: [Bind classes to Global Scope in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38796519)

Comment: So even when A is in my scope (A is defined), I can no longer evaluate "A"?

Comment: That's correct. You could always do `window.A = A;`

Comment: Not via a string. `A` exists in the current scope. This also happens to be the global scope. However, it's not added to the global object which is `window` for browsers. It's part of the design of ES6 to reduce the global pollution and name clashes. You can also just do `window.A = class A {}` but I'd really advise against it. If you need an object as a registry, then just use an object as a registry.

Comment: But it's better to use your own object for this rather than polluting the `window` object.

Comment: @IrinaRapoport well you can always `eval('A')` if that's what you really want. But if you want to lookup some classes by strings, use a `Map`.